# Get chats list MongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb

In my chat app (+20m users for example) i need to get last updated chats but there's no optimal solution.

**Chats**

```
{
  id: 1,
  title: 'My Group',
  updated_at: 137974654
},
{
  id: 2,
  title: 'Gamers',
  updated_at: 137973654
}
```

**Members**

```
{
  chat_id: 1,
  user_id: 'A'
},
{
  chat_id: 2,
  user_id: 'B'
}
```

I don't want to embed `members` because a user can join thousands of chats so document size is beyond 16MB.

> The maximum BSON document size is 16 megabytes.

> A potential problem with the embedded document pattern is that it can lead to large documents, especially if the embedded field is unbounded. In this case, you can use the subset pattern to only access data which is required by the application, instead of the entire set of embedded data.
>
> https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-embedded-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/#subset-pattern

### My solution but not efficient

I first tried to get a list of chat_ids then query `chats`:

```js
const members = Members.find({ user_id: 'A' }).project({ chat_id: 1 });
const chat_ids = members.map(item => item.chat_id);

const chats = Chats.find({
  id: {
    $in: chat_ids
  }
}).sort({ updated_at: -1 }).limit(20);
```

But as i said, What if a user has joined +100000 chats? so the first query is too large + the last query is too slow.

What should i do? Do i need a relational database?

Comment: how about adding an extra time field on members collection, and updating the new time field for the member whenever there is an insert/update on chat for that member

Comment: @indybee again, what if the chat has +100000 members and updating those records every time a new message is sent? not efficient even worse.

Comment: I was assuming you would only need to update the new timestamp for the member only if that member did a post on the chat. It seems like that isn't case.

Answer (score 0):

Making some assumptions that you are only interested in `user_id: 'A'`, and keeping in mind that I am a MongoDB noob, and I only tested this with the example data you provided, does this do what you want?

```
db.members.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      user_id: "A"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "chats",
      localField: "chat_id",
      foreignField: "id",
      as: "thechats"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$thechats"
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$thechats"
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      updated_at: -1
    }
  },
  {
    "$limit": 20
  }
])
```

Try it at [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TfXdzD9E-3S).